# Bootstrap with Main Left Navbar causes content nav menu to have same vertical size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap based site with a navbar vertically aligned on the left of the screen. On some of the pages I want the page content to have its own nav menu place horizontally across the top of its own content.

**Problem:** My problem is that using bootstrap classes for both navigation menus, the horizontal nav menu in the content area has the same height as the main vertical navigation menu. This pushes all the content not only below the content's nav menu, but below the much taller main navigation menu - when the content should be beside the main menu!

**Question:**
How do I get the content's nav menu to vertically size for its own content so the content area's full content will flow beside the main navigation menu?

Using the [F12] developer tools in IE, FireFox, and Chrome, I cannot see any reason why the heights of both navigation menus is synchronized, and thus I can find no why to break that synchronization.

The problem is replicable on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zazm460q/2/
*(I am developing for desktop apps, you may have to widen the `Result` pane to see the desktop layout rather than the mobile layout.)*

Here is some simplified HTML showing the problem:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse nabvar-static-top">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a href="#">My App Logo</a>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar-left navbar-inverse">
  <ul class="nav nav-pill nav-stacked" id="main-nav">
    <li class="panel">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#a" data-parent="#main-nav">menu item a</a>
      <ul id="a" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse in">
        <li>
          <a href="#">a.1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">a.2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">a.3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="panel">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#a" data-parent="#main-nav">menu item b</a>
      <ul id="b" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse">
        <li>
          <a href="#">b.1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">b.2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">b.3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="panel">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#a" data-parent="#main-nav">menu item c</a>
      <ul id="c" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse">
        <li>
          <a href="#">c.1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">c.2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">c.3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="panel">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#a" data-parent="#main-nav">menu item d</a>
      <ul id="d" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse">
        <li>
          <a href="#">d.1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">d.2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">d.3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="panel">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#a" data-parent="#main-nav">menu item e</a>
      <ul id="e" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse">
        <li>
          <a href="#">e.1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">e.2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">e.3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="body-content">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar-inner">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-a">Tab A</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-b">Tab B</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-c">Tab C</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-d">Tab D</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-a">Tab-A Content Here
        <p>
          AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-b">
        <h1>Tab-B Content Here</h1>
        <p>
          BBBBBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-c">
        <h2>Tab-C Content Here</h2>
        <p>
          cccccc ccccccCCCCCCC CCCCCcccccc cccCCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCcccc cccccc
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-d">
        <h3>Tab-D Content Here</h3>
        <p>
          DDDDDDDDDDD ddddddddddddd DDDDDDDDDDDDD ddddddddddd DDDDDDDDddd
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>My App</footer>
```

And also some simplified CSS:

```css
nav.navbar-left {
  width: 140px;
}

#body-content {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can solve this is to use the default Bootstrap Nav as both a vertical (sidebar nav) and horizontal (standard nav) Navigation at the same time.

Then create a new container/wrapper class for your content to offset the Sidebar.

Working Examples.

**Tab Content within Columns Example:** *Use FullPage and reduce the Browser width.*

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-nav .navbar-nav.navbar-left {
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    background: #222;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar-nav.navbar-left > li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #222;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .main-content {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .main-content .nav-tabs {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .main-content .nav-tabs > li {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .main-content .nav-tabs > li > a {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    padding: 20px 0;
    color: #222;
  }
  .main-content .nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #f3f3f3;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
  }
  .main-content .nav-tabs > .active >a,
  .main-content .nav-tabs > .active >a:focus,
  .main-content .nav-tabs > .active >a:hover {
    border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
  }
}
.main-content .nav-tabs > li > a {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.tab-inner-content {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css rel=stylesheet><nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse sidebar-nav"><div class=container-fluid><div class=navbar-header><button class="collapsed navbar-toggle"data-target=#bs-nav data-toggle=collapse type=button><span class=sr-only>Toggle navigation</span> <span class=icon-bar></span> <span class=icon-bar></span> <span class=icon-bar></span></button> <a href=# class=navbar-brand>Brand</a></div><div class="collapse navbar-collapse"id=bs-nav><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a><li class=dropdown><a href=# data-toggle=dropdown aria-expanded=false aria-haspopup=true class=dropdown-toggle role=button>Dropdown One<span class=caret></span></a><ul class=dropdown-menu><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a></ul><li><a href=#>Four</a><li class=dropdown><a href=# data-toggle=dropdown aria-expanded=false aria-haspopup=true class=dropdown-toggle role=button>Dropdown Two<span class=caret></span></a><ul class=dropdown-menu><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a></ul><li class=dropdown><a href=# data-toggle=dropdown aria-expanded=false aria-haspopup=true class=dropdown-toggle role=button>Dropdown Three<span class=caret></span></a><ul class=dropdown-menu><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a></ul><li class=dropdown><a href=# data-toggle=dropdown aria-expanded=false aria-haspopup=true class=dropdown-toggle role=button>Dropdown Four<span class=caret></span></a><ul class=dropdown-menu><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a></ul></ul><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a></ul></div></div></nav><div class=main-content><div class=container-fluid><div class=row><div class=col-md-6><div class=content><ul class="nav nav-tabs"><li class=active><a href=#tab1 data-toggle=tab>Tab 1</a><li><a href=#tab2 data-toggle=tab>Tab 2</a><li><a href=#tab3 data-toggle=tab>Tab 3</a><li><a href=#tab4 data-toggle=tab>Tab 4</a><li><a href=#tab5 data-toggle=tab>Tab 5</a><li><a href=#tab6 data-toggle=tab>Tab 6</a></ul><div class="tab-content tab-inner-content"><div class="fade tab-pane active in"id=tab1><h3>Tab 1</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<hr><img class=img-responsive src=http://placehold.it/850x425/000/fff><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div><div class="fade tab-pane"id=tab2><h3>Tab 2</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<hr><img class=img-responsive src=http://placehold.it/850x425/000/fff><hr></div><div class="fade tab-pane"id=tab3><h3>Tab 3</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<hr><img class=img-responsive src=http://placehold.it/850x425/000/fff><hr></div><div class="fade tab-pane"id=tab4><h3>Tab 4</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<hr><img class=img-responsive src=http://placehold.it/850x425/000/fff><hr></div><div class="fade tab-pane"id=tab5><h3>Tab 5</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<hr><img class=img-responsive src=http://placehold.it/850x425/000/fff><hr></div><div class="fade tab-pane"id=tab6><h3>Tab 6</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<hr><img class=img-responsive src=http://placehold.it/850x425/000/fff><hr></div></div></div></div><div class=col-md-6><div class=content><hr><img class=img-responsive src=http://placehold.it/850x425/000/fff><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div></div></div></div></div><script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js></script><script src=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
```

**Full Width Tab Content:** *Use FullPage and reduce the Browser width.*

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-nav .navbar-nav.navbar-left {
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    background: #222;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar-nav.navbar-left > li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #222;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .main-content {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  .main-content .nav-tabs {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .main-content .nav-tabs > li {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .main-content .nav-tabs > li > a {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    padding: 20px 0;
    color: #222;
  }
  .main-content .nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #f3f3f3;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
  }
  .main-content .nav-tabs > .active >a,
  .main-content .nav-tabs > .active >a:focus,
  .main-content .nav-tabs > .active >a:hover {
    border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
  }
}
.main-content .nav-tabs > li > a {
  border-radius: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-content {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
}
.tab-inner-content {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css rel=stylesheet><nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse sidebar-nav"><div class=container-fluid><div class=navbar-header><button class="collapsed navbar-toggle"data-target=#bs-nav data-toggle=collapse type=button><span class=sr-only>Toggle navigation</span> <span class=icon-bar></span> <span class=icon-bar></span> <span class=icon-bar></span></button> <a href=# class=navbar-brand>Brand</a></div><div class="collapse navbar-collapse"id=bs-nav><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a><li class=dropdown><a href=# data-toggle=dropdown aria-expanded=false aria-haspopup=true class=dropdown-toggle role=button>Dropdown One<span class=caret></span></a><ul class=dropdown-menu><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a></ul><li><a href=#>Four</a><li class=dropdown><a href=# data-toggle=dropdown aria-expanded=false aria-haspopup=true class=dropdown-toggle role=button>Dropdown Two<span class=caret></span></a><ul class=dropdown-menu><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a></ul><li class=dropdown><a href=# data-toggle=dropdown aria-expanded=false aria-haspopup=true class=dropdown-toggle role=button>Dropdown Three<span class=caret></span></a><ul class=dropdown-menu><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a></ul><li class=dropdown><a href=# data-toggle=dropdown aria-expanded=false aria-haspopup=true class=dropdown-toggle role=button>Dropdown Four<span class=caret></span></a><ul class=dropdown-menu><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a></ul></ul><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li><a href=#>One</a><li><a href=#>Two</a><li><a href=#>Three</a></ul></div></div></nav><div class=main-content><div class=nav-content><ul class="nav nav-tabs"><li class=active><a href=#tab1 data-toggle=tab>Tab 1</a><li><a href=#tab2 data-toggle=tab>Tab 2</a><li><a href=#tab3 data-toggle=tab>Tab 3</a><li><a href=#tab4 data-toggle=tab>Tab 4</a><li><a href=#tab5 data-toggle=tab>Tab 5</a><li><a href=#tab6 data-toggle=tab>Tab 6</a></ul><div class="tab-content tab-inner-content"><div class="fade tab-pane active in"id=tab1><h3>Tab 1</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div><div class="fade tab-pane"id=tab2><h3>Tab 2</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div><div class="fade tab-pane"id=tab3><h3>Tab 3</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div><div class="fade tab-pane"id=tab4><h3>Tab 4</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div><div class="fade tab-pane"id=tab5><h3>Tab 5</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div><div class="fade tab-pane"id=tab6><h3>Tab 6</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div></div></div></div><script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js></script><script src=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
```